# EXIST SQL Simplify

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

```
-- Insert statements for procedure here
IF EXISTS
(SELECT S.SCHEDULER_ID FROM Scheduler S WITH (NOLOCK)
 INNER JOIN CaseDetails_Scheduler_Mapping CDSM WITH (NOLOCK) ON (S.SCHEDULER_ID=CDSM.SCHEDULER_ID)
 INNER JOIN CaseDetails CD WITH (NOLOCK) ON (CDSM.CASE_DETAIL_ID = CD.CASE_DETAIL_ID)
 WHERE S.HEARD_BEFORE_ID=@HEARD_BEFORE_ID AND S.SCHEDULE_START_TIME=@SCHEDULE_START_TIME AND S.SCHEDULE_DATE=@SCHEDULE_DATE)
BEGIN
    SELECT '4' AS 'STATUS', (SELECT S.SCHEDULER_ID FROM Scheduler S WITH (NOLOCK)
     INNER JOIN CaseDetails_Scheduler_Mapping CDSM WITH (NOLOCK) ON (S.SCHEDULER_ID=CDSM.SCHEDULER_ID)
     INNER JOIN CaseDetails CD WITH (NOLOCK) ON (CDSM.CASE_DETAIL_ID = CD.CASE_DETAIL_ID)
     WHERE S.HEARD_BEFORE_ID=@HEARD_BEFORE_ID AND S.SCHEDULE_START_TIME=@SCHEDULE_START_TIME AND S.SCHEDULE_DATE=@SCHEDULE_DATE) AS 'SCHEDULER_ID',
     (SELECT CD.CASE_NO FROM Scheduler S WITH (NOLOCK)
     INNER JOIN CaseDetails_Scheduler_Mapping CDSM WITH (NOLOCK) ON (S.SCHEDULER_ID=CDSM.SCHEDULER_ID)
     INNER JOIN CaseDetails CD WITH (NOLOCK) ON (CDSM.CASE_DETAIL_ID = CD.CASE_DETAIL_ID)
     WHERE S.HEARD_BEFORE_ID=@HEARD_BEFORE_ID AND S.SCHEDULE_START_TIME=@SCHEDULE_START_TIME AND S.SCHEDULE_DATE=@SCHEDULE_DATE)   AS 'CASE_NO'
END
```

I know this code are correct , but is there a way to simplify my sql code? i try did select 2 column in 1 table but it will appear "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS" error..... Sorry if i asking such beginner question..

Comment: How would you determine a "right" answer from this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can remove the `IF EXISTS` part. Here is a simplified version of your `THEN` part:

```
SELECT 
    '4' AS [STATUS],
    S.SCHEDULER_ID  AS [SCHEDULER_ID],
    CD.CASE_NO AS [CASE_NO]
FROM Scheduler S WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN CaseDetails_Scheduler_Mapping CDSM WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON (S.SCHEDULER_ID = CDSM.SCHEDULER_ID)
INNER JOIN CaseDetails CD WITH (NOLOCK)
    ON (CDSM.CASE_DETAIL_ID = CD.CASE_DETAIL_ID)
WHERE 
    S.HEARD_BEFORE_ID = @HEARD_BEFORE_ID
    AND S.SCHEDULE_START_TIME = @SCHEDULE_START_TIME
    AND S.SCHEDULE_DATE = @SCHEDULE_DATE
```

Note that [putting `NOLOCK` everywhere is considered a bad habit](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/).

Comment: WOW, just now i do almost like this but come out error "Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS" .. maybe because i didt close the open barack .. nway THANKS much .... i will read thru about NOLOCK...

Comment: I like all your answers ;)